# How to call parent methods in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, date, oop, groovy

I'm new to Java and groovy , I mostly code in Python.I'm trying to understand why the code doesn't work.
The error i'm getting is
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static HelloWorld.TestingProduct() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

I've been tasked to add eventdate as sysdate on a project, and I'm just trying to understand how to add it by testing locally

```
import groovy.transform.ToString
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter



public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String[] args){
        String testin = TestingProduct().Inventory()
        System.out.println(testin);
     }
}


class Parent {

   private String setDateNow() {
        OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
        return formatter.format(now);
    }
}

class TestingProduct extends Parent {
   private static ProductInventoryEvent Inventory(){
      def invent = new ProductInventoryEvent(
         productId:'1',
         productIdType:'2',
         eventType:'3',
         eventDate: setDateNow(),
      )
      return invent
   }
}


@Canonical()
@ToString(includeNames = true)
class ProductInventoryEvent {
    String productId
    String productIdType
    String eventType
    String eventDate

}
```

Comment: `TestingProduct` is a class. To create new class you have to use `new` keyword: `new TestingProduct()`. without `new` - it's a function/method call.

Comment: I tried with ```new``` , now I'm getting ```groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static TestingProduct.setDateNow() is applicable for argument types: () values: []```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things that are wrong in your code. Let me first start with the `HelloWorld` class.

You are trying to access/call static method `Inventory` of the `TestingProduct` in a wrong way. In order to access static methods you do not need any object instance of that class. So, instead of `TestingProduct().Inventory()` you should use `TestingProduct.Inventory()`.

Second thing is that, your method `Inventory()` is returning `ProductInventoryEvent` and not a string. So you should change the type of the variable that you want to initialize. Here is how the code should look like:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      ProductInventoryEvent testin = TestingProduct.Inventory();
      System.out.println(testin);
    }
}
```

Another thing that you should change is the access modifier of the `Inventory()` method in the `TestingProduct` class. Instead of private, you should use package private or public access modifier. So the code should look like:

```
public class TestingProduct {
   static ProductInventoryEvent Inventory(){
      def invent = new ProductInventoryEvent(
            productId:'1',
            productIdType:'2',
            eventType:'3',
            eventDate: setDateNow(),
      )
      return invent;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also i think, you can't call private method in parent´s class. you have to change the access modifier to protected